# Change datepicker date format according to saved in database

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datepicker

sorry for the noob question but is it possible to change the date format in date picker?

I have searched in google but the only thing I see is either I change the CultureInfo or set the StringFormat.

I tried binding the StringFormat but I realized that it is not a DP.

So is it possible to change date format? Let's say:

Formats in database:
mm/dd/yyyy
dd/mm/yyyy
yyyy/dd/mm
yyyy/mm/dd
...(etc)

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

This can help you..

**Match the format first**
(in the array, add more formats to check)

```
string[] formats = {"M/d/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy",                                    
                            "d/M/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                            "yyyy/M/d", "yyyy/MM/dd",
                            "M-d-yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy",                                    
                            "d-M-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", 
                            "yyyy-M-d", "yyyy-MM-dd",
                            "M.d.yyyy", "MM.dd.yyyy",                                    
                            "d.M.yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy", 
                            "yyyy.M.d", "yyyy.MM.dd",
                            "M,d,yyyy", "MM,dd,yyyy",                                    
                            "d,M,yyyy", "dd,MM,yyyy", 
                            "yyyy,M,d", "yyyy,MM,dd",
                            "M d yyyy", "MM dd yyyy",                                    
                            "d M yyyy", "dd MM yyyy", 
                            "yyyy M d", "yyyy MM dd"
                           };

        DateTime dateValue;

        foreach (string dateStringFormat in formats)
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(sqlDateTime, dateStringFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
        }
```

**Then change it to your format**

```
var x=dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); // or any other format
```

Comment: I tried this the first time and it failed. Format is dd/mm/yyyy. First displays correctly (Feb 6, 2017 or 06/02/2017). Now choose a different date. Say, Feb 7, 2017 (display will be 07/02/2017) then click the date picker and try to select a new date. The date displayed will be in July 2, 2017.